# Printing documents to tiff

Tags: printer, tiff

I have a faxing program that only accepts TIFF files to send. It don't have any utility to convert documents to TIFF and i have to convert them myself. Even worse, **it only accepts monochrome TIFF Files with 200x200 dpi and Width of 1728 pixels!**

I found [Peernet TIFF Image Printer](http://www.peernet.com/tiff/index.html) that is really perfect. It sets up a Virtual Printer and i can print anything and anywhere to TIFF format! But it is not free and i cannot pay any more extra $100 !

Is there any software that could do it for me?

Is there any way to install a tiff printer? I found something about ghostscript and how to setup a Virtual Tiff Printer, But i was not simple and i don't know where i should set 200x200dpi and Width=1728pixel

Comment: Use [Print to TIFF](https://superuser.com/a/1344326/928593) (author is Pascal Damman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [BullZip PDF Printer](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php). It has an option for printing to TIFF and allows you to set the resolution. I'm not sure about how you would guarantee a width of 1728 pixels (probably by changing the size of the original document), but it might be worth having a look.

Answer (score 2):

1728 pixels width at 200dpi gives a page width of 8.64in, which translates to 622pt (PostScript points). This is roughly the width of Letter (612pt)... So what is the page ***height*** you are allowed to use? If you use Ghostscript's "tiffg4" output and specify the width in pixels, you also need to specify the height in pixels.

Note, the above suggestion to run Ghostscript with `sPAPERSIZE=letter` will not create a TIFF with a width of 1728 pixels as required by you. It will use 612 PostScript points, which translate into 1720 pixels only.

You can use Ghostscript on Windows to create the TIFF with exactly the resolution and width/height you need. Here is an example command (using a height of 2200 pixels and a width of 1728 pixels at 200dpi):

```
gswin32c.exe ^
    -dBATCH ^
    -dNOPAUSE ^
    -sDEVICE=tiffg4 ^
    -dPDFFitPage ^
    -sOutputFile=c:\temp\page-%04d.tif ^
    -r200x200 ^
    -g1728x2200 ^
    c:\path\to\input\pdf
```

Comment: How did you calculate 1720 px from 612 pt?

Comment: @Marvin: It's in the very first sentence, isn't it ?!?

Comment: Well no, the first sentence shows how to translate 1728 px into 622 pt.
With that calculation, you get 1700 px for 612 pt, and 619 pt for 1720 px.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/). From the website:

> Key Features:
>
> - safe-to-install awardCreate PDFs from any program that is able to print
> - Security: Encrypt PDFs and protect them from being opened, printed etc
> - New: Digitally sign your PDFs to ensure that you are the author and the file has not been modified
> - New: Create PDF/A files for long term archives
> - Send generated files via eMail
> - Create more than just PDFs: PNG, JPG, **TIFF**, BMP, PCX, PS, EPS
> - AutoSave files to folders and filenames based on Tags like Username, Computername, Date, Time etc.
> - Merge multiple files into one PDF
> - Easy Install: Just say what you want and everything is installed
> - Terminal Server: PDFCreator also runs on Terminal Servers without problems
> - And the best: PDFCreator is free, even for commercial use! It is Open Source and released under the Terms of the GNU General Public License.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of PDF printers have an option to print to tiff. I haven't got one that prints to tiff installed myself, but that may be an option.

I also found some instructions for [setting up ghostscript with tiff printing](http://server3.nethost.co.il/set_tif.html). You need to add a line to the tif.rsp file to set the resolution.

I think this is -r200. e.g.

```
-Ic:\gs\gs8.00\lib;c:\gs\fonts
-sDEVICE=tiffg4
-sOutputFile=c:\print.tif
-dNOPAUSE
-dSAFER
-dBATCH
-sPAPERSIZE=letter
-r200
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had good experience with both:

1. [Bullzip](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php)
2. [Polestar](http://www.polestarsoft.com/download/)

Polestar is slightly better, as it allows you to specify resolution etc before you print.

Comment: Polestar doesn't have any option for setting resolution of TIFF images. It only have this option for PDFs.

Comment: It does right next to the PDF settings under "Image" section