# How to print as a bitmap?

Tags: windows, printing, jpeg, png, pictures

When using programs that allow printing, in the Print dialog I can choose to print the output to a PDF instead of sending to a physical printer (for example, selecting the "`Microsoft Print to PDF`" printer option).

Is there a similar way to print to some bitmap file format, like JPEG, TIFF, PNG, etc.? Possibly this will require multiples image files, one per document page.

Comment: AFAIK, most of the apps have options to "Save as JPEG" or similar.. that should do.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on what software you are using.  Some applications allow exporting or saving as a different file format.  Microsoft has the Print to PDF option, as it is a very common thing for people to convert a format to PDF, as it a universal format.

You would have to check your software's manual to know if it can save as or export to a different format.  Some do, some dont.

As for print to bitmap, I have only seen print drivers that print to PDF and HTML, but not images types.  They may exist, but I wouldnt expect them to.

That being said, you can always use a screen capture tool that can capture full window contents and save to a bitmap.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am aware of "Export" option in standard "File" menu of specific software. Unfortunately, this is not available in most of them. Hence, the question was specifically targeted at the print dialog, which is relying on printer drivers or virtual printer drivers, and not the specific software in use.

Comment: @ysap Other than printing to pdf and html, I havent seen anything else... doesnt mean that dont exist, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of the following: [How to print documents to pictures (gif, bmp etc.) on windows](https://superuser.com/questions/35590/how-to-print-documents-to-pictures-gif-bmp-etc-on-windows) and the answer still holds. There are multiple paid software options (and limited free options) for virtual printer drivers that will allow the creation of various image files instead of something like a .pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

Taken at face value without any addition to Windows, there are limited options, with mixed success for such a task.

Just to prove there is a poor mans very manual option. (Not recommended but the minimum entry point.)
Traditionally you can print to G4 Fax which is Monochrome TIFF (200 dpi).
[image]

The next simpler option **was** historically print to image in "Black&White" or "Color", to JPEG or PNG in a ZIP. Which was generically extractable via an automated Filename.XPS. However more recent XPS files no longer seem to have such contents just poor thumbnails or icons. Image print output would be only from convertible image input sources !

Traditional print options are usually vector but often programmers will output to a PostScript Format and use that for command line image conversion in say Artifex (private not commercial) GhostScript.

I declare, I support SumatraPDF which can ONLY print to image (hence the knowledge of problems). Thus could be abused producing 600dpiXPS, but controls will generally not be good enough for most users. Thus would for wider better scope, suggest Artifex MuTool convert.

Here is Print this Page.PDF from SumatraPDF (one exe) as **PNG.XPS** and extracted (can be done using cmd line, but suggest there are easier routes using MuPDF.)
[image]

Thus its primarily down to 3rd party solutions, and there are plenty of shareware and freeware "Virtual Image Printer" offerings, many with mixed very powerful abilities.

Comment: Thanks. So if I follow, you suggest printing to a fax or to PDF, then using the respective program to export to an image?